# Limits of subrings and surjectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, schemes

Let $A$ be a ring and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the inductive system of subrings of $A$ which are of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$:
$$
\mathcal{F} = \{ \mathbb{Z}[a_1,\dots,a_n] \subseteq A \mid n \geq 0, \ a_1, \dots, a_n \in A \}.
$$
I'd like to know whether the following statement is true:
*For every $B \in \mathcal{F}$, there exists $C \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $C \supseteq B$ and the map $\mathrm{Spec}(A) \to \mathrm{Spec}(C)$, induced by the inclusion $C \hookrightarrow A$, is surjective.*

Maybe EGA IV.8.3.8.(i) is useful, but I have no ideas to prove or disprove the statement. Any hint will be welcome. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true: if $A$ is a local ring, then $C$ must be local too. Now assume that $B$, thus $C$,  contains at least one element that is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $C$ as a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra has infinitely many maximal ideals.

Comment: Thanks! A simpler example is $A = \mathbb{Q}$, because every subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $\mathbb{Z}[1/d]$ and the map $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}) \to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[1/d])$ cannot be surjective.